# Return if the related model has a value or not as a new field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have Post model and related Likes item. I am trying to return the if the related model has a row for authenticated user or not. So the tables look like:

```
Posts
- id
- body
- etc

Likes
- id
- user_id
- likable_type
- likeable_id
```

Now I am return Posts eloquent with `Posts::get()`, however I want to return every model with a parameter inside `is_liked` which shows if the authenticated user has liked that post or not.

If I use `->with('likes')->where(function($q)) {}` approach, it will only return me the Post that user has liked but this is not what I want.

I want every Post object to show if the authenticated user has liked it or not. Such as: `Post { id, body, is_liked }`

Is there any way of achieving this beside running a for loop? What is the best way to handle such scenario?

---

**Update**

```
class Post extends Model {
       protected $appends = ['is_liked'];

       public function getIsLikedAttribute() {
          return $this->has('likes.user_id', '=', Auth::id())->exists();
       }

      public function likes() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Like', 'likeable');
      }
}

class Like extends Model {
   protected $fillable = [
      'user_id', 'likeable_id', 'likeable_type'
   ];

   public function likeable() {
      return $this->morphTo();
   }
}
```

Writing through this morph works, however, `$this->has('likes.user_id'` part returns error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user_id does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use am accessor and add that property to the append protected variable:

```
protected $appends = ['is_liked']; 

public function getIsLikedAttribute() { 
   return $this->likes()->where('user_id',  '=',  Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

Now you can also check the accessor like

```
$post->is_liked // bool
```

Comment: Do I add it on Post model? Also, how do I perform it inside the query `Post::get()`? I am using Laravel api so I get the user as $request->user() rather than Auth - through api:auth

Comment: @senty You can pass parameters to the accessor like the user in this case

Comment: Can you please show it in the answer? I receive error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user_id does not exist.`

Comment: @senty What version are you using? I've changed the answer to a more version friendly one

Comment: Laravel 5.6. I think I understand the Model side but not the fetching side. To simplify, if I use Post::get(), how would I give it the user_id in the controller and let it return me the value in the `Post::get()`?

Comment: @senty Adding it to the appends variable

Comment: I debugged it, and made Auth work. in `'likes.user_id'` this part, I have the problem; even though the current model has public function `likes() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Like', 'likeable');
    }`

Comment: I added that for simplifying stuff. I updated the OP, can you please check?

Comment: @senty Have you tried my answer after the update? The first answer was not version friendly

Comment: @senty There you go! Glad it helped you :)